# how to get the number of pages from a pdf file based on a keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can get the pages where the keyword is found. But now what I would like to do is use the format of the keyword like **Bold** or *Italic* and get all the pages until it finds the same format like **Bold**. Is it possible to do?

I have used the following code to get the page where the specific keyword exists.

```
# Store the page numbers
page_num = []
# Open the PDF file
    with fitz.open('example.pdf') as pdf:
        # Search for a specific keyword
        keyword = 'keyword'
        page_number = None
        for page in pdf:
            # Extract text from the page
            text = page.get_text()

            # Search for the keyword in the text
            if keyword.lower() in text.lower():
                page_number = page.number
                # print(page_number)  
                page_num.append(page_number)

    if page_number is not None:
        print(f'More detailed information on "{keyword}" can be found on page(s) {page_num}. \n')
    else:
        print(f'"{keyword}" was not found in the document. \n')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Page`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html) has a method [`get_text`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.get_text) which gives you the page content in a [dictionary format](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textpage.html#structure-of-dictionary-outputs). The spans have a flag, which tells you if it is in italic or bold.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textpage.html#span-dictionary), the flags are:

> bit 0: superscripted (2^0) – not a font property, detected by MuPDF code.
>
> bit 1: italic (2^1)
>
> bit 2: serifed (2^2)
>
> bit 3: monospaced (2^3)
>
> bit 4: bold (2^4)

Using this you can find the pages where a keyword appears either bolded or in italics like so:

```
import fitz

page_num = []
# Open the PDF file
candidate_fonts = set()
with fitz.open('example.pdf') as pdf:
    # Search for a specific keyword
    keyword = 'keyword'
    page_number = None
    for page in pdf:
        d = page.get_text("dict")
        for block in d["blocks"]:
            for lines in block["lines"]:
                for span in lines["spans"]:
                    if keyword.lower() in span["text"].lower():
                        candidate_fonts.add(span["font"])
                        flags = span["flags"]
                        if flags & 2**1 or flags & 2**4:
                            page_number = page.number
                            page_num.append(page_number)

if page_number is not None:
    print(f'More detailed information on "{keyword}" can be found on page(s) {page_num}. \n')
else:
    print(f'"{keyword}" was not found in the document. \n')
```

If you only care about the keyword in bold or only in italics you need to adjust the if-condition accordingly.